# How do ordering by rank and fields relate to each other in Sphinx search?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

Suppose I have a query like this:

```
SELECT <somefields>
FROM example
ORDER BY somefield ASC
OPTION ranker=bm25
```

This seems contradictory. How is it going to sort? By `somefield` only? Or by BM25 rank only? Or both? If both then which is the most important? Can I use both like `somefield ASC, rank DESC` or `rank DESC, somefield ASC`? How can I disable sorting altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ordering by somefield only**. There is an implicit `ORDER BY WEIGHT() DESC`, but if set any order, it completely overrides the implicit value.

... can choose to use weight in multisort, eg

```
ORDER BY somefield ASC, WEIGHT() DESC
```

In your example query, the actual calculated weight would be unused. Its not in sort, its not in the select. In fact sphinx might internally change to the 'none' ranker anyway, but can choose it explicitly

```
OPTION ranker=none
```

THere is no 'completely unsorted', can't say `ORDER BY NULL` or whatever.

Comment: Can I use `@rank` instead of `WEIGHT()`? I have old code with such usage. It used to work in older version of Sphinx and now it doesn't. But it was not listed in changes.

Comment: I found answer to that. `@rank` was removed in version 3